# How to add header and footer to a PDF file by rendering HTML page

Tags: python, html, django, reportlab, pisa

I have generated a pdf file by rendering an HTML page. Here is what i did for that

```
return render_to_pdf(                
                html,
            )


def render_to_pdf(html):
    result = StringIO.StringIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode('utf-8') ),  
              dest=result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), 
              content_type='application/pdf')
```

So this will give me a pdf file against the inputted HTML file.

I want to add header and footer for this pdf file , is there any way that i can do this dynamically. Dynamically in the sense for the first page in the pdf i need a footer and in the second page i need another footer that will be different from the first one, and in other page may have different footer so and so. So is there any way that i can include such feature in this, by specifying the page number. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean "dynamically" - just modify the `html` you receive and add whatever you need?

Comment: Is there any way that i can say footer and header from the server side itself?. It will be easy for me if there is any option for saying the header and footer from here itself without adding them in the html file.